# oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513)

Tags: java, jar, ojdbc

```
package test;
import java.sql.*;
public class ConnectionDatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {       
        try 
        {

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            String query="insert into EMPLOYEE(idNo,name,phoneno,address,salary)"+
            "values(1,'Mike',234232,'Queens',80000);";
            Statement st= con.createStatement() ;
            int rows =st.executeUpdate(query);
            if(rows>0)
            {
                System.out.println("A row has been inserted");
            }
            
            con.close();

        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("error:-");
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }   
}
```

after complilation i am obtaining this error
error:-

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:41)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:928)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1712)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1699)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:285)
    at test.ConnectionDatabase.main(ConnectionDatabase.java:22)
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 92, Sql = insert into EMPLOYEE(idNo,name,phoneno,address,salary)values(1,'Mike',234232,'Queens',80000);, OriginalSql = insert into EMPLOYEE(idNo,name,phoneno,address,salary)values(1,'Mike',234232,'Queens',80000);, Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: What you show is not a compilation but a run-time error. Try removing semi-column( `;`) from the end of your SQL statement.

Comment: dang...my bad for this silliness, thanks.@PM77-1